# Write a Test for extension HELP

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Hi Im new working with apexcode and I Crate a Class in sanbox, but when I try to upload to production it says that my coverage code is 73%

this is my code

```
public with sharing class New_Session_Extension {

public Talleres__c taller {get; private set;}
public String entregables {get; private set;}
public String tipodetaller {get; private set;}
public Gastos__c gasto {get; private set;}

public New_Session_Extension (Apexpages.StandardController sc) {
    this.gasto  = (Gastos__c)sc.getRecord(); 
    this.entregables = '';
    this.tipodetaller = '';
    
    if(this.gasto.Entregable__c == null) {
        this.taller =  [SELECT Id,Entregables_E1__c,Taller__c FROM Talleres__c WHERE Id = :this.gasto.Taller__c];
        this.entregables = this.taller.Entregables_E1__c; 
        this.tipodetaller = this.taller.Taller__c; 
    } else {
        this.taller = new Talleres__c();
        this.entregables = this.gasto.Entregable__c;
    }

 }
}
```

any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask} for getting the most from the community. In particular, you need to [edit] and include your testclass

Comment: I dont have a Test Class :(

Comment: go to Trailhead and learn how to write a test class; see also [VF Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm). The Community ethos will help you if you demonstrate that you have tried to write a test class but won't write it for you

Comment: Yea I get it, thanks